# How to save logs in Eclipse without saving information about execution?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

I actually use log4j to save my log file.
The information saved in the file is like that :

> 2016-01-28 17:18:41,895 [       SynchroDerbi.java:main:56] - Logger
>   Test

Now I want to save just the part "Logger Test" 
I want something like : Logger Test

How can I remove the other part of the message? Or can I use a simple other logger instead of using lg4j?

Comment: Read the log4j documentation about PatternLayout

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is there any other simple logger which can resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your log4j configutaion file (most probably log4j.properties) change pattern to: %m%n

m: Used to output the application supplied message associated with the logging event.

n: Outputs the platform dependent line separator character or characters.

(this makes what you want for the time being, but most probably you will return that original layout which also shows the location of logger in code and log event time)

[PatternLayout javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)